# Dividing $n+2$ balls to $n$ bins such that no bin is empty

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, balls-in-bins

> We have $n+2$ balls and $n$ bins, in how many ways we can divide the balls between the bins such that there's no empty bin? (Bins are different and numbered)

My attempt: for the first bin we have $n+2$ options, for the second bin $n+1$ options, etc, for the last bin we have 3 options, when every bin has one ball we have two balls left, there are $n$ options for each ball so the final answer is: $\frac {(n+2)!}{2}\cdot n^2$

EDIT: The balls are different. (sorry I forgot to add that)

Comment: So you're counting all surjective functions from $n+2$ to $n$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/264814/4280 (Stirling numbers of the second kind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each bin must have at least 1 ball, you only free to choose how to place the remaining two balls. They can either both go in the same bin ($n$ ways to do this) or in different bins ($\binom{n}{2}$ ways to do this). Thus
$$
n+\binom{n}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}.
$$

UPDATE: the balls being distinct changes things. There are $\binom{n+2}{n}$ ways to select how to fill the bins with 1 ball each. Then there are $n!$ ways to order each selection for a total of
$$
n!\binom{n+2}{n}
$$
ways to fill the bins with 1 ball each. The last two balls can either both go in the same bin ($n$ ways to do this) or in different bins ($2\binom{n}{2}$ ways to do this). The factor of two is from the fact that once I have selected the individual bins to put the remaining balls in, there are 2 distinct ways to fill them. Thus
$$
n!\binom{n+2}{n}\left(n+2\binom{n}{2}\right).
$$

Comment: It took me a while to see that $n!\binom{n+2}{n}=\frac {(n+2)!}{2}$ so at least I got that right.. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: I would get too hung up on simplifying the expression. There are lots of ways to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

The so called [Stirling number so the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) S(n,k) is the number of ways to distribute $n$ different objects over $k$ undistinguished subsets. In this case we have $n+2$ objects and $n$ distinguished bins, so we get $n!S(n+2,n)$ as the number.

Now use the explicit formula from the Wikipedia page.

Comment: I really need to remember this. I jump right in to counting a forget about things like the Stirling numbers.

Comment: This leaves us with an expression that has sums no?