# How many finite sequences with exactly k different elements?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

How many different sequences/strings of length $\ell$ contain exactly $k$ (out of $n$) different elements?

Or, to put it differently, how many functions from $\{1,\dots,\ell\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ have the property that their image is of size exactly $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose the $k$ elements, in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, then count the number of surjective functions from $\{1,\dotsc, \ell\}$ to those $k$ elements, in $k!S(\ell,k)$ ways (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264799/calculating-the-total-number-of-surjective-functions)).